# stable conformation of 2,3-dimethylsuccinic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

I was researching for answering this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166474/kolbes-electrolysis-reaction-for-alkenes-production) on Kolbe's electrolysis of 2,3-butanedicarboxylic acid (succinic acid). Turns out, this compound is not very well researched in particular, and shows few results on search engines. I did find some results for 2,3-dimethylbutanedioic acid (2,3-dimethylsuccinic acid). [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/11848) shows the anti-conformer as the standard structure.

[image: structure of 2,3-dimethylbutanedioic acid]

Now, the compound has two stereogenic carbons and 3 isomers:

1. R-R
2. R-S
3. S-S

Do any of these isomers under any conditions show higher stability for the syn-conformer? I ask because of the possibility of $\ce{H}$-bonding:

[image: hydrogen bonding in 2,3-butanedimethyl]

Would the stability due to $\ce{H}$-bonding be enough to overcome the steric repulsion?

---

As told in comments, the above schematic has a 7-membered ring, which are generally less stable than 6-membered rings. This prompted me to draw another diagram which has two 7-membered rings instead:

[image: hydrogen bonding in 2,3-dimethylbutanedioic acid]

I see that the rings are somewhat strained, but that doesn't mean that, at least, one of the two hydrogen bonds does not form.

Comment: As to your concern about the lack of references to the Kolbe process, try: J. Meyers, et al., Intramolecular Biradical Recombination of Dicarboxylic Acids to Unsaturated Compounds: A New Approach to an Old Kolbe Reaction, ChemElectroChem, **2020**, 7 (24), 4873-4878.

Comment: There is no *cis*-isomer. If you are addressing the favored hydrogen-bonded conformation, the least one can say is that what is true for the *R,R*-stereoisomer is true for the *S,S*. Remember, you are dealing with a 7-membered ring, not a 6-membered ring.. Perhaps a computational guru can help with an answer.

Comment: @user55119 You say one 7-membered ring. I draw two 7-membered rings. What do you say now?

Comment: I believe your original question was about which diastereomer is more strongly, intramolecularly hydrogen-bonded. That issue is still in abeyance. As to your new doubly hydrogen-bonded structure, it does not add to the resolution of the question at hand.

Comment: Yes indeed, the question does deal with the diastereomers as well. I did find some [evidence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040402001924378) suggesting that the syn-conformer is more stable than the anti-conformer.